# Override default LDAP user creation behavior with ASP.NET Boilerplate/Module-Zero

Tags: ldap, aspnetboilerplate

Let me start by saying that the ASP.NET Boilerplate Module-Zero LDAP integration is working as expected.

My question is can I override the default behavior of this module.

By default, when an LDAP user first authenticates to the application, it generates a user account for each user and assigns them the default user profile.

My intention is to deny access to the user, until someone manually stubs out their user account and assigns their role (basically turn off auto-user creation).

Please share if you have thoughts on how to achieve this with ASP.NET Boilerplate/Module-Zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the document [How to create external authentication source](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication)

I think you can override `CreateUserAsync` method. After LDAP authentication successfully, create new user and just set him as inactive.

Comment: This worked quite well, thanks for providing a direction to head in, and the relevant documentation link.  I decided to go the override route.

Answer (score 1):

I perform the override by implementing my own Ldap auth source.  Here is the class code, in case others find it useful.

```
using Abp;
using Abp.Zero.Ldap.Authentication;
using Abp.Zero.Ldap.Configuration;
using MCMT.Quotes.Authorization.Users;
using MCMT.Quotes.MultiTenancy;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace MCMT.Quotes.Authorization.Ldap
{
    public class AppLdapAuthenticationSource : LdapAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>
    {
        private readonly ILdapSettings _settings;
        private readonly IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig _ldapModuleConfig;

        public AppLdapAuthenticationSource(ILdapSettings settings, IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig ldapModuleConfig)
            : base(settings, ldapModuleConfig)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _ldapModuleConfig = ldapModuleConfig;
        }

        public async override Task<User> CreateUserAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, Tenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(userNameOrEmailAddress, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userNameOrEmailAddress);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + userNameOrEmailAddress);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);

                user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;
                user.IsActive = false;

                return user;
            }
        }

        public async override Task UpdateUserAsync(User user, Tenant tenant)
        {
            await CheckIsEnabled(tenant);

            await base.UpdateUserAsync(user, tenant);

            using (var principalContext = await CreatePrincipalContext(tenant))
            {
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user.UserName);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    throw new AbpException("Unknown LDAP user: " + user.UserName);
                }

                UpdateUserFromPrincipal(user, userPrincipal);
            }
        }

        protected override void UpdateUserFromPrincipal(User user, UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
        {
            user.UserName = userPrincipal.SamAccountName;
            user.Name = userPrincipal.GivenName;
            user.Surname = userPrincipal.Surname;
            user.EmailAddress = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;
        }

        private async Task CheckIsEnabled(Tenant tenant)
        {
            if (!_ldapModuleConfig.IsEnabled)
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication module is disabled globally!");
            }

            var tenantId = GetIdOrNull(tenant);
            if (!await _settings.GetIsEnabled(tenantId))
            {
                throw new AbpException("Ldap Authentication is disabled for given tenant (id:" + tenantId + ")! You can enable it by setting '" + LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled + "' to true");
            }
        }

        private static int? GetIdOrNull(Tenant tenant)
        {
            return tenant == null
                ? (int?)null
                : tenant.Id;
        }
    }
}
```